# Make nav link current for specific webpage

Tags: php, html, css

I want to create current state for my nav links in my website.
For example when I click "Contacts" the link refers me to contacts page and I want the link "contacts" in nav to change his color.

The problem is that I'm including the header from external html file in all my webpages with php. So if I edit this external header file the changes will affect all other pages not only the contacts page.

Comment: don't you think such situation is a very common situation used in almost all the websites ? ... so don't tell me you found no clue searching on google ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `id` of the body of the page to some value that represents the current page. Then for each element in the menu you set a class specific to that menu item. And within your `CSS` you can set up a rule that will highlight the menu item specifically.

That probably didn't make much sense, so here's an example:

```
<body id="index">
<div id="menu">
 <ul>
  <li class="index"     ><a href="index.html">Index page</a></li>
  <li class="contact"     ><a href="contact.html">Page 1</a></li>
 </ul>
</div> <!-- menu -->
</body>
```

In your `contact.html`, you would set the id of the body to: `id="contact"`.

Finally in your CSS you have something like the following:

```
#index #menu .index, #contact #menu .contact{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

You would need to alter the ID for each page, but the CSS remains the same, which is important as the CSS is often cached and can require a forced refresh to update.

It's not dynamic, but it's one method that's simple to do, and you can just `include` the menu html from a template file using PHP or similar.